# SQLite - Returning column total w/all rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQLite table:

```
transaction_amount     transaction_date
50                     09/06/2012
50                     09/06/2012
75                     09/07/2012
```

I wish to get the total amount for the column, transaction_amount. If I write my SQL query like this:

```
SELECT transaction_amount,transaction_date, SUM(transaction_amount) AS 
Total FROM prepaid_tbl WHERE playerID = 17 ORDER BY id DESC
```

I get the following result:

```
 transaction_amount     transaction_date  Total
 75                     09/07/2012        175
```

I need all three rows returned along with the total. So, if I write the SQL Statement like this:

```
SELECT transaction_amount,transaction_date,(SELECT SUM(transaction_amount) 
FROM prepaid_tbl WHERE playerID = 17)Total FROM prepaid_tbl WHERE 
playerID = 17 ORDER BY id DESC
```

I now get the results I am looking for:

```
transaction_amount     transaction_date    Total
50                     09/06/2012          175
50                     09/06/2012          175
75                     09/07/2012          175
```

So, my simple question is this the best method/practice for getting my desired results. I am not an SQL expert by any means, so I am still  uncertain as to why the first method isn't returning the results I want. Any insight is certainly appreciated.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `cartesian join` to solve you problem

```
SELECT  a.transaction_amount,
        a.transaction_date,
        b.Total
FROM prepaid_tbl  a,
        (
            SELECT  SUM(transaction_amount) AS  Total 
            FROM prepaid_tbl 
            WHERE playerID = 17 
        ) b
WHERE a.playerID = 17
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a3eb/1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried your SQL Statement and it only returns the row total in each Total field (i.e.50,50,75) . I want to return the sum (175) in the Total field.

Comment: yeah, that for my first answer. see my updated answer :D Hope it workednow.

Comment: It does thanks! So, in short, if I need to get a sum/total for a column, I will **ALWAYS** need to use a secondary SELECT statement within the query.